# How do I turn on live reloading(using an express server) for frontend development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express as the server and nodemon to reload that server on file changes. Works perfectly. But when I make a frontend change (i.e changing an html page or css, javascript, anything basically) I have to reload the browser manually. If you're like me, that isn't ok. I know of the vscode extension "Live Server", but I want it all to be in that one express server. I tried using the live-reload npm package, the app and the browser extension, but that didn't work out for me. I really don't want to have to start to use something like webpack just so I'm saved the effort of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> a couple times. Any recommendations? I still haven't learned React but I've heard that if you use React, then you'll have that live reloading feature. I'm actually currently developing a typescript website template, so that's what I want to use it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said and after a little searching *maybe* [samuelgjabel/nodejs-hot-reload](https://github.com/samuelgjabel/nodejs-hot-reload) is what you're looking for?

It supports typescript and where you don't want to roll your own / learn webpack at the moment, this seems like it would keep things simple.

**disclaimer* - I haven't used the library myself and cannot attest to it's security or quality.

---

**update:**

Regarding your comment response, My mistake I misunderstood.

This library works on the front-end providing the auto (CTRL-R) you're looking for. try [this guide](https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/) for [connect-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-livereload)

It seems to hook into express' connection event to signal the browser for a reload after nodemon has respawned the server instace. The guide shows how to implement it without a build tool like gulp/grunt.

Comment: Tried, from what I can see it does refresh the server just like nodemon, but I need something to Ctrl+R the browser in a way, so it doesn't suit my needs. As said in the github repo page, it's a node.js hot reload library, but I already have nodemon up and working, so no help there :)

Comment: I tried this one, doesn't work sadly... Did everything showcased in the tutorial, but still nothing.
EDIT: Sorry, what I just needed was to include the high port number in the app.use(). Works like a charm. If anyone is interested, I can share the code from my app.ts file.